# Review Queues Automatically Clear

Tags: bug, review

Not sure if this is an undocumented feature, when I'm asked to review, I get different topic queues

> Close Votes
>   First Posts
>   Late Answers
>   Low Quality Posts
>   Reopen Votes
>   Suggested Edits

If I start at the top of the list, when I'm done with that topic queue, if there are more reviews in other topic queues below, they all clear out.

If I start at the bottom of the list and work my way up, all the requests stay (except for the ones I already reviewed)

Shouldn't it work the same working up the list as working down the list?

I haven't found anything when searching for "review" about this.

Comment: Note that there can be situations where a post ends up in two or three review queues, e.g. in the First Posts, Late Answers and Low Quality Posts queues. If you review the post in one of them, it will not appear anymore in the others.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that all of them clear up *by-design*. However,

As far as I'm concerned, (**review queues**: VLQ = Very Low Quality, FP = First Posts, LA = <s>Los Angeles</s>Late Answers, CV = <s>‎Curriculum Vitae</s>Close Votes)

- A new user's first answer to an old question will appear in *both* FP and LA review queues. If it's been flagged too, it would also appear in the VLQ queue.

  - If you reviewed it in LA or FP first, and then it got flagged, you can review it again in VLQ for a second time.
  - If you reviewed it in VLQ, you won't see it in LA or FP anymore. Note that the post did exist in those queues before you clicked on VLQ, so **you saw three reviews where only one was necessary**.
- A question is both flagged for closure and as VLQ. It will both appear in VLQ and CV.

  - If you vote to close in VLQ, it will no longer appear in CV for you.
  - If you review it in CV, it will no longer appear in VLQ.

On larger sites, there may also be the issue of heavier caching. The reason for all of this is that tasks that **you** can get done at any moment are displayed, not the total amount of tasks that need reviewing.